# Mezzanine BlogCategory parsing categories

Tags: mezzanine, django-filters

I want to build a custom filter that takes a blog_post as an argument and does some parsing of the categories (attached to the blog post).

I tried like this:

```
from mezzanine import template
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost, BlogCategory

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_friends')
def has_friends(blog_post):
  categories = blog_post.categories.all()
  if 'Friends' in categories:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

The problem is that blog_post.categories.all()  returns something like this:

```
[<BlogCategory: Enemies>, <BlogCategory: Allies>, <BlogCategory: Friends>, <BlogCategory: Family>]
```

Questions:

1. how can I get the list of categories parsed like this ['Enemies', 'Allies', 'Friends', 'Family'] instead of above (in order for my *if* statement to work)  ?
2. without the answer at above question 1, how can I use IF statement to search in the BlogCategory list shown above?

Thank you,

GG

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself, this way:  I used dir(category) to get its methods => found among: title, slug, etc...
then I use:

```
for category in categories:
    if category.title == 'Friends':
        # do stuff
```